# Angular 7 - multiple classes (spaces) causes ngClass to fail

Tags: css, angular, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

A lot of frontend frameworks encapsulate their CSS styling by prefixing it with another class.

Eg bootstrap: `btn btn-primary` where `btn` is the prefix.

If I were to conditionally apply this in an `[ngClass]`, angular would break:

`<div [ngClass]="{'btn btn-primary': booleanVar, 'btn btn-danger': !booleanVar}"></div>`

However, this would be easily solved by extracting the common denominating class like this:

`<div class="btn" [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': booleanVar, 'btn-danger': !booleanVar}"></div>` Voilà,  we no longer have any spaces in our conditions, and angular approves.

Now with some context. Lets try to apply this to approach to `Font Awesome`, their prefixes can be found [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use).

```
Style       Prefix  Example 
Solid       fas     <i class="fas fa-igloo"></i>    
Regular     far     <i class="far fa-igloo"></i>    
Light       fal     <i class="fal fa-igloo"></i>    
Brands      fab     <i class="fab fa-font-awesome"></i>
```

**1st question**: Is it possible to use spaces in a conditional query? *how*?

**2nd question**: (if 1st question is not possible) How would I solve a situation where the **prefix no longer is static** (like in the case of Font Awesome)?

Comment: Did you find solution to this?

Comment: @Bozhinovski yeah i did, can't remember at this moment unfortunately (and i've left the company a few years ago). Think i solved with a ts-solution.

Comment: I've had the exact issue lol, cant believe ngClass is not accepting multiple classes. Anyway, thanks mate

Comment: Yeah, i know, i remembered being frustrated too. I got an idea tho you could wrap the final-class-output as the returned value from a function perhaps. Give it a try! :)

Answer (score 1):

Update, I checked and using spaces is fine.

So this

```
<div [ngClass]="{'btn btn-primary': booleanVar, 'btn btn-danger': !booleanVar}></div>
```

should work.

Also you can use this format;

`[ngClass]="booleanVar ? 'btn-primary': 'btn-danger'"`

Comment: `[ngClass]="{ booleanVar ? 'btn-primary': 'btn-danger'}` is not a correct object.

Comment: @trichetriche, it works not with brackets but within the quotes

Comment: I know, but you did use the brackets. Keeping the downvote because your solution doesn't actually provides a solution, it only parrots the question.

Comment: The good with SOF is that you have an history of the edits. So no, I didn't downvote while you were editing it. I downvoted, then commented, then you deleted your comment, and edited it; to finally answer my comment by one of yours. Anyway, this answers seems acceptable, I'm removing my downvote !

Comment: @trichetriche, I did not say that you downvoted while I edited. You downvoted first, you commented and then I deleted. I completely agree. I was telling that I was checking the syntax if it was right or wrong and got to know that it was wrong

Comment: @Joel, What I was trying to say is that having a space should not create any issue ideally. So even if you want to use the classes from font-awesome which have space, it should work. i.e., <div [ngClass]="{'fal fa-igloo': booleanVar, 'fab fa-font-awesome': !booleanVar}></div>

Answer (score 0):

You do it class by class :

```
[ngClass]="{'btn': true, 'btn-primary': booleanVar, 'btn-danger': !booleanVar}"
```

Comment: But... As I mentioned in the question... The prefix is not static, that's like the entire point of the question. I even provided an example for what you just answered.

Comment: @Joel and the entire point of my answer is that you do it class by class. So you also do it prefix by prefix.

Comment: Don't know if you(re playing dumb or purpose or not, so I'll play along for this one : `{'fas': conditionOne, 'far': conditionTwo, 'fa-igloo': conditionThree }`. **One by one**.

Comment: I just used `true` because it's the example you have provided, and it happens that `btn` was in both conditions, and `false || true === true`.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're trolling now. Imagine scaling this up, are you *really proposing* this as the optimal answer? In aJS this worked fine. So, i'm wondering what the correct approach would be in a7. Imagine if one would want to add classes dynamically, then this approach would be... well, lets put it nicely.. **not optimal**.

Comment: @Joel I don't imagine, I answer questions. You asked for a particular use-case, I answered. If I were to implement that on a high scale, I would have a custom component for that, that would hide/show the icons instead of changing the classes in a single one. This is another question, that you should have asked if you wanted a solution.

Comment: hence my 1st question... (which I see no answer of) - so I guess you *don´t* answer questions after all, and, I do not see any answer to my 2nd question either. Not really sure what you are answering here. This is still static, i'm asking for **what if the prefix is not static**.

Comment: You proved yourself it isn't possible, why would I answer it ... Be sassy if you want to, you're just dense. I'm not losing more time for you. Good luck with your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your well-wishes. You seem like a very self-aware and empathic person. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had this exact problem on a Angular 7 project and after some tinkering I discovered where the issue is. **It is normally possible to add multiple space-separated classes with ngClass**, but if the same class appears in multiple conditions it will be removed if one of the later conditions is false. For example:

```
<span [ngClass]="{
    'fas fa-book': val === 1, 
    'fas fa-eye': val === 2, 
    'far fa-star': val === 3 }">
</span>
```

when `val === 3` there's no problem, when `val === 1`, the `fas` class will be removed, while when `val === 2` the `fas` class will be removed, then added back again so it works fine.

What I suspect is that they are just executed in order and if the condition is true the element's classes are added but if the condition is false they are all removed no matter what, I haven't seen Angular 7 code with my eyes but all my tests point to this.

Let's say `val === 1`, then first angular will add the classes `fas` and `fa-book`, but then (since `val === 2` is `false`) will remove the classes `fas` and `fa-eye` from the `span`.
When `val === 2` instead, first the `val === 1` case will be evaluated and it will remove the classes `fas` and `fa-book`, but then it will evaluate the `val === 2` case and add the `fas` class back, so it will work fine

Anyways, at this point the only solution I found when you have the same class on multiple conditions is to reorganize your code in order to have the shared classes in a different condition, like this:

```
<span [ngClass]="{
    'fas': val === 1 || val === 2, //val !== 3 would've been fine too in this specific case
    'fa-book': val === 1, 
    'fa-eye': val === 2, 
    'far fa-star': val === 3 }">
</span>
```

Here's a Plunkr showing the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/EouOaIfBkIR5Q29n?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1 (change the "val" value inside app.ts. 1 will not work for the first span while 2 and 3 will work for both cases)